# Stop KDE/Plasma Hiding Mouse Cursor When Typing

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, kde, wacom

How can I stop KDE/Plasma from hiding the cursor when typing?

I'm using kUbuntu with a wacom instead of a mouse. When using some applications like konsole the cursor is hidden when you begin typing. When using a standard mouse once you move the mouse again the cursor is revealed. However with a wacom when you start moving the cursor it is not revealed until you either click somewhere blindly or leave the window.

Comment: check the mouse settings in system settings

Comment: It basically only lets you change the cursor speed and the handedness of the buttons.